# In UNIX shell script, How do I loop through all files in a directory while excluding some specific files?

Tags: shell, unix

I have 1000+ file in a folder, and I would like to use a for loop (in Shell script) to loop through all of them, except for some specific files with a certain prefix.

For example:

```
exposureRawFilePath="/aa/bb/*.psv.gz"

sizmekfiles="aa/bb/abcd*.psv.gz"

for dr in $exposureRawFilePath ; do

for dr not in $sizmekfiles ; do
```

I tried these commands above but they did not work. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Which shell, specifically? Bash, or POSIX sh?

Comment: BTW, putting your glob expression in a variable is actually a bad idea -- it creates a lot of trouble if your script is used with a filename with spaces, since unquoted expansions don't just do globbing but also do string splitting. Much saner to expand the variable into an array and thereby evaluate it up-front, if targeting a shell (like ksh or bash) with array support. That is: `sizmekfiles=( "aa/bb/abcd"*.psv.gz )`, and then later `for dr in "${sizmekfiles[@]}"; do`... though if your shell is bash you can also use `extglob` syntax to get a glob that skips files, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) :

```
for file in /aa/bb/*.psv.gz; do
    [[ $file == /aa/bb/abcd* ]] && continue
    echo "$file"
done
```

or with [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) :

```
shopt -s extglob # need for bash if not already enabled, ksh enable it by default

for file in /aa/bb/!(abcd*); do
    echo "$file"
done
```

---

or even for [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) :

```
for file in *; do
    case $file in
        /aa/bb/abcd*.psv.gz) continue ;;
        *) echo "$file" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Done, post edited accordingly, was my first thought, But had issues with testing ^^

Comment: `!(prefix*).suffix`, perhaps, given the OP's actual pattern. (I suppose the `in *`s in the other examples might be `in *.suffix`, if we were to spoonfeed in that manner).

Comment: No need the suffix tough

Comment: ...not sure I follow. If the OP didn't want to filter out files lacking the suffix, why would it be there in the code showing their own attempts?

Comment: Thanks guys for your solutions!  I would follow the extglob method.

Comment: If it fit your needs, thanks to accept the answer by clicking the large checkmark on the left of the answer. This is how SO works

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged `bash` in your question so here is a `POSIX` way to get your job done using `case`:

```
for f in /aa/bb/*.psv.gz; do
   case "$f" in
      /aa/bb/abcd*.psv.gz)
         continue;;
      *)
         echo "processing $f";;
   esac
done
```